# Determining if the current locale uses non-arabic numerals in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

In iOS I'd like to perform some specific functions if the user's `[NSLocale currentLocale]` does not use [Arabic Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) (i.e. not 0123456789).  How can I check for this condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct attribute to check, but the following code will check it:

```
NSCharacterSet *nSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"];
NSNumberFormatter *numFmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *value = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1234567890"];
NSCharacterSet *fSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[numFmt stringFromNumber:value]];
if([fSet isSupersetOfSet:nSet]==NO){
    NSLog(@"No arabic digits");
}
```

The check is done via a set of the digits (nSet) against the locale aware formatter of the current locale (numFmt). The value is used to format a number of all digits, which could be reduced to less digits than 1 to 0. However this might serve as an example of other detections as well.
Please note that using a separator or thousand grouping character will not break the detection because superset is being used.

Comment: @Volatil3 You might want to start a new question to explain the specifics of your case.  But initially I'd say that everything is handled for you.  Use NSString's -floatValue or -intValue to get the number from your UITextField, and process the maths as normal.  Then display your result in localized form by using NSNumberFormatter's -localizedStringFromNumber

Comment: @Volatil3 right, but using the Formatter to parse would be the best option.